# Using Laravel Excel to import multiple sheets, but not getting formatted cell values

Tags: laravel-8, phpspreadsheet, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using laravel excel to import multiple sheets with formatted cell value of phone number with format cell "+1"# but while importing, in collection rows not getting formatted value. Already used  WithFormatData in app/Import/SheetImport.php. already bug was closed as fixed [here](https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/issues/2739) but not working.

Am'i missing anything here.

I tried multiple solution given on stackoverflow and in github issues but not getting expected output, same import excel functionality is returning formatted value with codeigniter phpspreadsheet.